# Ansible - subclass of a role

Tags: ansible

We're creating an overall Ansible codebase which is used by various departments to spin up their own environments.

What's the best way of having a common codebase and then allowing each department to configure their own servers?

Here's a specific example. Say we have the role:

roles/apache

containing the `defaults/`, `tasks/`, `vars/` directories.

However, Department A might want to ensure there's a `/var/www/html` directory whereas Department B might want a `/opt/www` directory.

How would you create a basic template role that allows A and B to create their own directories?

Answer (score 1):

For example:

Define default variable in `defaults/main.yml`:

```
dirs_list: ['/var/www/html']
```

Make a task to create required directories in `tasks/main.yml`:

```
- file:
    path: '{{ item }}'
    state: directory
  with_items: '{{ dirs_list }}'
```

This way Dept A can call the role with defaults:

```
roles:
  - apache
```

and Dept B can override defaults:

```
roles:
  - role: apache
    dirs_list:
      - /opt/www
      - /var/somepath
```